# Django: Get objects of first model by comparing attribute of second OneToOne related model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models, User and Card. One user has one card. I need to get objects of User if the 'card_written' of Card model is False in a view.

```
class User(model.Model):
    phone           =   PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    email           =   models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)

    first_name      =   models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name       =   models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Card(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    card_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    card_written = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
    card_write_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    card_delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query on related models quite easily in Django by separating related fields by double underscores.
A query like this should work for you:

```
User.objects.filter(card__card_written=False)
```

Here card is the related name since you haven't specified it in the Card model if you want it to be something else you need to specify like so in the Card model:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='something_else')
```